# Entire page flashes white when switching between pages

Tags: html, css, django, heroku

I've been developing a web application locally which transitions seamlessly on link clicks around the site.

Now I've decided to deploy my web application to heroku.

Everything is working as expected, except when I click links within the site, there is an annoying white flash over the entire page as it loads.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have content that loads and/or blocks page rendering and/or Heroku not serving the content fast enough for your browser so that's why it displays a white flas.

You would have to go through your entire site in order to fix it. It could be a delay in JavaScript.

Why you're not experiencing this locally is because you serve your assets faster than on Heroku.

Try a tool like [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) and see what's happening with your site.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by:

- moving my css links into the head of the page
- moving my javascript files right before the closing  tag
- Switching my self hosted jquery file to the google CDN devlivered jquery file